# AddColum with embedded object (Vaadin or just Java skill)

Tags: java, vaadin8

I'd like to insert the property(string) of an embedded object with addColumn.

My code is just :

```
tarifsLignesGrid.addColumn(TarifsLignes::getProducts).setCaption(TITRE_PRODUITS)
```

the getProduct return a Product entity in which I'd like to take the name property instead of the toString.

Comment: You should add context, but I took a stab at answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot more context would be nice, but I'll take a stab in the dark. Assuming the Product class has a `getName()` method:

```
tarifsLignesGrid.addColumn(t -> t.getProducts().getName()).setCaption(TITRE_PRODUITS)
```

Comment: Sorry for the context I ll do it next time, and thanks a lot for this good answer.
I'm not really familiar with this way of writing.
Thanks again

Comment: @Wise If this solved your problem, please upvote and accept my answer

Comment: you solved it but I can't upvote your answer to new in stackoverflow.
Thanks again